# how to pass url from controller / model to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model that has a property like "SomeUrl", it's an absolute url with some parameters in it, something like this for example:  http://www.someexternalsite.com/q?param1=value1&param2=value2

My view takes a List and I am trying to use these url's in an anchor tag like this:

```
<a href="@Model.SomeUrl">my link</a>
```

The url is being encoded and ends up coming out like this:

```
http://www.someexternalsite.com/q?param1=value1&amp;param2=value
```

How do I stop it from doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not encoding the & would result in invalid html. In this case the html is correctly encoded. If you want to render a string not encoded use:

```
@Html.Raw(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your link to this:

```
<a href="@Html.Raw(Model.SomeUrl)">my link</a>
```